# Взять значения из текста

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Имеется такой текст :

```js
Date: Fri, 01 Apr 2016 03:21:49 GMT
Server: nginx
Content-Type: application/x-rar-compressed
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Keep-Alive: timeout=15
Content-Length: 63000000
```

или он может быть еще примерно таким:

```js
Date: Fri, 01 Apr 2016 03:17:30 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 13 Dec 2014 08:28:52 GMT
Server: nginx
ETag: W/"548bf8c4-28496"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

В общем, нужно спарсить (если нету текста со значением то пропуск,как например в первом примере есть Content-Lenth: ... , а во втором нету)
следующее :
Content-Type: ..... (может быть только что то типа application/exe , image/png и т.д)
Content-Length: ..... (могут быть любые цифры)
как это можно сделать? 
учитывая что один или оба значения могут отсутствовать

Comment: что-то я не понял, что вы хотите подавать на вход, и что хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: на вход подавать 1 текст или 2,а получать Content-Length = .... и Content-Type = ..... (где точки там спарсенный текст)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
var text = 'Date: Fri, 01 Apr 2016 03:21:49 GMT \
Server: nginx \
Content-Type: application/x-rar-compressed \
Cache-Control: no-cache, private \
Connection: keep-alive \
Accept-Ranges: bytes \
Keep-Alive: timeout=15 \
Content-Length: 63000000';

var result = false;
if( result = text.match( /Content-Length:\s*(\d+)/ )) {
  console.log(result[1]);
}
if( result = text.match( /Content-Type:\s*([^\s]+)/ )) {
  console.log(result[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Почему бы вам для начала не разбить это на массив строк? 
А дальше каждую строку парсить , ведь у вас строка имеет вид `ключ`: `значение`

```
/**
Date: Fri, 01 Apr 2016 03:21:49 GMT
Server: nginx
Content-Type: application/x-rar-compressed
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Keep-Alive: timeout=15
Content-Length: 63000000
*/

var txt; // текст выше
var lines = txt.split('\n'); // получаем строки
// теперь можем работать уже с каждой строкой
for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var line = lines[i];
    var props = line.split(':');
    var key = props[0]; // заголовок
    var value = props[1]; // значение заголовка
}
```